# SASS/SCSS mark all properies !important using mixin or function

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Similar to `Required<T>` and `Partial<T>` mapped types of typescript do we have anything in SCSS where I can make all the properties of a class as mandatory.

To be more specific, here is the use case:
I have a class .body2 in a _font.scss file

```
.body2 {
  font-size: var(--font-sm);
  line-height: rem(20px);
  font-family: var(--font-base);
  letter-spacing: -0.2%;
}
```

and in someother file I have to give this style to a web component which is from some other code base.
Hence to override it I need to mark `!important`.
So instead of re-writing the same lines manually I want to extend this class .body2. as

```
 form input,
  textarea {
    @extend .body2;
    color: var(--white) !important;
  }
```

but this does not override the default style of web component as the properties are not marked as `!important`.
So I just wanted to know is there a mixin or function in SCSS which can help me in applying `!important` to all the properties of a class may be somewhat similar to `Required<T>` and `Partial<T>` in typescript.

Comment: You can override a style by using a more specific selector — you don't have to use `!important`. Important was mainly meant for end-user stylesheets so they could _override_ the site [6.4.2 !important rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules). Consider if you should be using important for this: [When Using !important is The Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) [CSS !important: Don’t Use It. Do This Instead](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixin with parameter. Use `false` for default value.

```
@mixin a($isImportant: false) {
  @if $isImportant {
    font-size: var(--font-sm) !important;
    line-height: rem(20px) !important;
    font-family: var(--font-base) !important;
    letter-spacing: -0.2% !important;
  } @else {
    font-size: var(--font-sm);
    line-height: rem(20px);
    font-family: var(--font-base);
    letter-spacing: -0.2%;
  }
}

form input,
textarea {
  @include a;
  color: var(--white) !important;
}
```

Send `true` parameter for adding !important

```
form input,
textarea {
  @include a(true);
  color: var(--white) !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am not looking in this direction